# Is this method for exporting files is correct?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Hello what do you think of this way, to import all my files (of directory) ending with Handler.js, and then all export

[Screen of the folder where the files are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXGtd.png)

index.js:

```js
const {join} = require('path')
const {readdirSync, readFileSync, lstatSync} = require('fs')

const handlersPath = readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(fileName => /Handler.(js)$/.test(fileName))
  .filter(fileName => !lstatSync(fileName).isDirectory())
  
for (const handlerPath of handlersPath){
 const handlerName = /^(.*?)\Handler.js/.exec(handlerPath)[1]
 exports[handlerName] = require(join(__dirname, handlerPath))
}
```

Comment: but why? I mean, are you really lazy enough to not require them one by one, just when they are needed? But anyways, this question is too broad. If it does not produce errors, then yes it is correct...? Does it produce the wanted behavior? If not, explain.

Comment: No I'm not lazy to do them one by oner

Comment: using `sync` functions is an antipattern. it blocks all async functions.
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/

Comment: The index.js file is the importer once, and only at launch (server initialization)

Comment: @Adam yer, but in this use case, this seems about the right thing to do.

Comment: So I wonder if the asynchronous is really necessary

Comment: And what exactly are those handlers? What do they handle?

Comment: In fact, I get the message from the client with the name of the message in header, so I think it's easier to handle like this: handlers [messageName]

Comment: const handlers = require('./handlers')

Comment: @Salketer communication websocket

Comment: And what information would you like from us?

Comment: @Salketer Know if it is correct to handle this way, (except the synchronous that I will replace by the asynchronous)

Comment: Does the code work? Are there any errors?

Comment: @Salketer The code work

Comment: So then we can't help... If it works, stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const {join} = require('path')
const {readdir, lstat} = require('fs')

readdir(__dirname, (error, files) => {

 if (error) throw error
 
 for (const fileName of files){
  
       if (!/Handler.(js)$/.test(fileName)) continue ;
    
    lstat(fileName, (error, stats) => {
         
         if (error) throw error
   if (stats.isDirectory()) return ;
   
   const handlerName = /^(.*?)\Handler.js/.exec(fileName)[1]
   exports[handlerName] = require(join(__dirname, fileName))
   
    })
 }
})
```

Is it totally asynchronous like that?

Comment: It would be better to say that all are loaded then continue with a callback or import directly?